# Reset database with rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I want to use Heroku's [scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to reset my database once every day.

It's recommended to use rake tasks for the scheduler. This is what I've tried:

```
task :reset_database => :environment do
  `heroku pg:reset MY_DB:URL`
  `heroku run rake db:migrate db:seed`
  # some other ruby commands
end
```

But how would I do this correctly, because putting the heroku commands within backticks, which with bash [normally works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-bash-commands-from-ruby), doesn't work here:

`No such file or directory - heroku`

Comment: Can you tell me the path locations you where you put the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rake task:

```
namespace :reset_database do
  desc "Destroy all table entries."
  task :all => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
      if table != 'schema_migrations'
        table.singularize.camelize.constantize.destroy_all
      end
      # Use this if you want to use the normal seeds:
      # Rails.application.load_seed

      # Use this if you want to run another rake task:
      Rake::Task["foo:bar"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `load_seed` method loops my seed files infinitely. (I use this code for my seed files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19872375/3205492)

Comment: I changed the answer to include the possibility to start an other rake task. In case you have a more complicated problem you need to create a new question with all the code involved.

Comment: Genius! Thanks a lot! I only had to put the other rake tasks outside the each block.